# How do I store date using NSUserDefaults after I have the number in a variable using Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm new and stuck any help would be great! I am using Xcode to build my app.

I have an IBAction "button pressed", this generates random numbers, then I have a bunch of if statements. Ultimately if things match up my long long variable "coins" has a numeric value. Right now I just change that value as in coins = coins + 10 and then display it in a UILabel. I now need to store that value, after all the calculations, whenever the user presses the button. So that their total of "coins" is being added to or subtracted from. Additionally I will want to add and In App Purchase that ads to the "coins" variable. So I know I need a way to store the value, even when the app is closed and re-opened.

Is there a way to use NSUserDefaults to store that value, either within the original IBAction buttonPressed? Also Or any help at all or suggestions would be great! Thanks and sorry if this sounds lame, but I'm on my first app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a number in NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:coins] forKey:@"coins"];
```

To retrieve from NSUserDefaults and store it into coins:

```
coins = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"coins"] unsignedLongLongValue];
```

This is assuming you've declared coins as being an unsigned long long, and not a signed one. Also, there are convenience methods for storing NSIntegers if you want to go through those.

EDIT: Just realized you want to have IAPs, should've read more carefully. I recommend against storing anything of value (passwords, usernames, purchasable currency, highscores that can be submitted to an online leaderboard, etc) in NSUserDefaults. It's stored as a simple `.plist` (XML) which could be edited relatively easily as far as I understand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking it might be a little to easy. This would be purchasable currency. How would you recommend I store this? An outside server? If so do you have any tips or a direction you could point me in? The reality is, it's a simple game for my first time out. I'm not to worried about people hacking in for more credit, but I wouldn't want Apple to reject me based on that. Any thoughts you have on that would be helpful too! Thank You

Comment: I'm not too sure myself. NSUserDefaults is made mostly for preferences, so it's not very secure. The Keychain was really made for passwords and things, although you could probably find a way to stick it in there and it would be secure. Unless you want to start encrypting things and writing them out or storing them on a server (both of which seem to be overkill) there's not much to be done. I don't think Apple would reject your app if you used NSUSerDefaults, and since its just a simple game I'd say go ahead, then. It's not a big deal if one guy somewhere gets a thousand free coins. xD

Comment: Oh, also, one way to make things a little harder to change would be to change everything into NSData before saving it in NSUSerDefaults. Take the number, make it into a string, use the method of NSString to turn it into NSData using unicode, store that. To load, retrieve the data, create the string from it, and get the value. Storing NSNumbers directly results in a simple decimal string, while I'm pretty sure NSData is written out in Base64. It's still possible to edit it but most people probably wouldn't bother. Plus, if you used some weird key no one would even know what the hell it was.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help I appreciate it. I think I'll go with the NSUserDefaults method you gave and give it a go. Like you said if someone gets some free coins, more power to them! At least it would mean they want to play the game :)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, that's so true! If they didn't like the game, they wouldn't go through all that trouble. :p